# Почему не работают <?php вместо <?=

Tags: php

Есть учебный  код

```
<?php
$goods=selectAllItems();
foreach($goods as $item){ 
?> 
<tr> 
 <td><?= $item['title']?></td> 
 <td><?= $item['author']?></td> 
 <td><?= $item['pubyear']?></td> 
 <td><?= $item['price']?></td> <td><a href="add2basket.php" id="<?= $item['id']?>"> В корзину </a></td> 
</tr> 
<?php 
}
?>
```

И там внутри цикла используются открывающие теги типа `<?=`, а не `<?php`.

И если поменять на `?php` - тогда не работает. Не подскажете почему так? В чем нюанс?

Comment: в чем выражается `не работает` ? ...............`<?= `  сокращенно от `<?php echo`, а не просто `<?php `

Comment: Спасибо, теперь дошло, я думал это просто открывающий тег а не сокращение от echo. Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `<?= $something ?>` эквивалентно `<?php echo $something; ?>`.